# DOM Range clones are not immune to DOM changes

Tags: javascript, dom, range

I am making a clone of a DOM Range using cloneRange() function. If I then modify the original range object like this:

```
range.setStart(range.startContainer, 1);
```

The clone preserves the old `startOffset` as expected.

However, if I modify the DOM tree, then the clone's `startOffset` will also get affected. Is there an intentional internal wiring between the DOM tree and all ranges that are associated with it (clones included)?

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ndM9C/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. What happens to ranges under DOM mutation is specified in the [DOM Level 2 Range specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html#Level-2-Range-Mutation). The more recent [DOM4 Range specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-range) specifies this under the [mutation algorithms](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutation-algorithms) section (thanks to RobG for pointing that out).

Comment: Ranges are specified as all the nodes between a start and end node, therefore any mutation of the DOM should be reflected in the range. There is no need to specify what happens for insertions, the DOM 4 section on [mutation algorithms](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutation-algorithms) explains what happens to ranges in the *remove* algorithm since removal may remove the start or end node or both.

Comment: @RobG: I briefly looked at the mutation algorithms section of the spec and missed the bit about ranges. I think the spec would benefit from a link in the Range section to the mutation algorithms section to help fools like me. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: That's fine, the specs are in a constant state of flux at the moment, it's difficult to keep track of it all. I try to stick to DOM2 and HTML 4.01, it keeps life very much simpler. :-)

Comment: @RobG: I think the term is "living standard" :)