# Cloning a range doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, range

When i get a selection range, clone it, and then wipe out the content that was the source of the selection, why does the cloned object still get affected? I thought it would be independent (since it was cloned)

Here's the code: https://plnkr.co/edit/A3TADtyyqkS6sI8ZJeaA?p=preview

```
<p id='test' contenteditable="true">hello world</p>
```

```js
function test() {
    var r = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
    console.log(r)
    $('p').empty();
    console.log(r);
}

$(function() {
    $('p').on('click', test)
})
```

---EDIT---

Mozilla api documentation states: *The returned clone is copied by value, not reference, so a change in either Range does not affect the other.*

Could this just be a quirk of the jquery's empty() method?

Comment: What makes you say it's affected? The first echo comes out as: `Range {startContainer: text, startOffset: 4, endContainer: text, endOffset: 8, collapsed: false…}` and the second as `Range {startContainer: p#test, startOffset: 0, endContainer: p#test, endOffset: 0, collapsed: true…}` With the results in mind, I'm not able to make sense of your question.

Comment: i expected the two echoed lines to be identical. Shouldn't the clone be completely independent of whatever gets done to the document content?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the problem is in the way you're creating the range and the clone. I refer you to the MDN page on the topic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/cloneRange - When I do your example with their range acquisition/cloning method, both the echo statements are the same. ;) -

Comment: Not a problem with the jQuery `empty` method - I didn't use it. I nuked the content with `.textContent = '';` - you're trying to create a clone of something you shouldn't I suspect. This is the difference between your code and that shown on the MDN page - they create, assign and clone. You on the other hand, get a reference to and clone. While it seems that they should be functionally the same, my $10 says that it's an artefact of the underlying implementation. Do you find the same behaviour across different browsers?

Comment: I can't see how i'm incorrectly getting the range and cloning it. But I did find this link which pretty much says the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404787/dom-range-clones-are-not-immune-to-dom-changes

Comment: It seems to me that the answer lies in the first comment to the accepted answer of that link.

Answer (score 0):

I searched google a bit and found this solution.
please [CHECK](https://plnkr.co/edit/VgP5oIn6lvZPvpIgw9x9?p=preview) if it works as you need

```
function test() {
  var range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  console.log(range)
  var clone = range.cloneRange();
  console.log(clone)
  range.collapse(true);
  var markerElement = document.createElement("span");
  markerElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\ufeff"));
  range.insertNode(markerElement);
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(clone);
  setTimeout(function(){
   markerElement.parentNode.removeChild(markerElement);
  }, 250);
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what that code does? If so, this answer would be better if it had an explanation (see [answer]). Otherwise, just copying and pasting without attribution to the original source is against the license of SO and could be considered plagiarism.

Comment: Hmmm... not sure it really helps. I wanted to just distill this test down to 3 simple steps : (1) clone a selection range, (2) change the source from which the selection range was created, (3) look at the earlier-cloned range. Seems simple, but i'm a bit new to this, so I think i'm missing something obvious